# Two format number in a same cell

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Could you tell me, if it is possible to have two number format in one cell?
The number format will change depending on the result of another cell.

I attach the link to [my test file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x1oycItwx_I_69lQT03CsCJKPIwdTPPoOqL0k6-wWCY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you please be a little more clear on what the final format is supposed to be  - its confusing what your expecting the final answer to be based on the way your asking the question

Comment: I would like the next time, the number displayed in cell c11, the format of the cell to be adapted according to the choice of cell b11.
The choice x, in b11, displays cell c9 * 5, in time format.
The choice o, in b11, displays the cell c9 * 12, in the accounting format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the TEXT() object's help document: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?visit_id=1-636271325324199875-441828486&hl=en-GB&rd=1



I added the solution to your spreadsheet in cell H5:

=IF(B11="x";TEXT(C11;"0.00 €");TEXT(C11;"hh:mm:ss"))



Each TEXT's 2nd argument is updatable, i.e. you could have either: "0.00 €" or "€ 0.00" or "hh:mm" etc.

Comment: Hi @James Miller,
I did not know this function, and it's excactly what I needed :)
Thank you for your time.
Cordially.